# Azure Kafka Trigger: how to receive only events after a specified offset

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-functions, kafka-consumer-api

How can I start reading topic messages from a certain point using the Azure trigger? I've seen an explanation of how to do this using the "--offset" flag, but the trigger doesn't expose that.

I'm building a new integration for an existing topic with a large data flow rate and definitely do not want to get all previous messages (for whatever this client's retention period is). This is my first effort working with Kafka.

Comment: Check this link https://tsuyoshiushio.medium.com/azure-functions-kafka-trigger-performance-tips-concept-and-architecture-ec94a31d8b93

Answer (score -1):

Below is the code to excute offset

```
var config = new ConsumerConfig
{
    ...
    EnableAutoCommit = true // (the default)
    EnableAutoOffsetStore = false
}

...

while (!cancelled)
{
    var consumeResult = consumer.Consume(cancellationToken);

    // process message here.

    consumer.StoreOffset(consumeResult);
}
```

For Further information check check [Kafka Offset](https://docs.confluent.io/clients-confluent-kafka-dotnet/current/overview.html#store-offsets).

Also Check [Kafka Trigger](https://tsuyoshiushio.medium.com/azure-functions-kafka-trigger-performance-tips-concept-and-architecture-ec94a31d8b93) for complete information.

Comment: The code sample and the first link is for using Confluent's Kafka client. I need to know how to do this using Microsoft's Azure Kafka trigger. Tsuyoshi Ushio provides a lot of great information, but I'm still not clear on how to do this after reading all of his content that I can find.